# HTML5 2D game webgl?

Tags: html5, webgl, 2d

Estou ciente que grande parte dos motores de jogo 3D para HTML5 utilizam a tecnologia WebGL, porém tive uma dúvida quando o assunto é 2D. Alguns motores de jogo 2D para HTML5 fazem referencia as funções gl_xxx, ou seja, usam recursos da GPU pra desenhar 2D, porém vi alguns tutoriais que utilizam exemplos onde não parecem que utilizam nada relacionado ao WebGL, como se a renderização fosse feita pela CPU, é isso mesmo?

Ao desenvolver um jogo em 2D para HTML5, este será executado na GPU(via WebGL) ou CPU(software rendering)? Ou programador que define isso? Links com exemplos de diferentes formas para implementar uma plataforma 2D seriam úteis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `<canvas>` define uma região desenhável da tela. Você pode então obter um contexto que vai definir como será feito o desenho. Atualmente temos duas APIs de contextos, o `"2d"` e o `"webgl"`. Ambas são APIs diferentes para o mesmo efeito de desenhar na tela e muito do que é feito com uma pode ser feito com outra.

Quanto ao fato de utilizar a GPU, isso depende completamente da implementação. O WebGL pode perfeitamente ser implementado via CPU se o browser detectar que a placa gráfica inexiste ou não é suficiente. Da mesma maneira, a API para 2D pode fazer uso da GPU para partes da renderização. Não há nenhuma limitação quanto a isso, é uma questão de implementação.

O Chromium fez algumas modificações nesse sentido por volta de 2012: http://blog.chromium.org/2012/02/gpu-accelerating-2d-canvas-and-enabling.html

Comment: Ótimo! Agora pesquisando no google por "2d context vs webgl" posso retirar minhas dúvidas.